# Avoid branching code for degenerate cases in Fibonacci generator

Tags: c#, fibonacci-sequence, generator, ienumerable

I was writing a simple function that would return the Fibonacci sequence up to the nth term and for whatever reason started wasting a lot of time on it. Here's what I came up with:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Fibonacci(int n)
{
    int last = 0, 
        oneBefore = 0;

    if (n > 0) yield return oneBefore = 0;
    if (n > 1) yield return last = 1;
    if (n > 2)
    {
        while (n-- - 2 > 0)
        {
            yield return last = oneBefore + (oneBefore = last);
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty close to what I want, but it has those three ugly if branches at the top level. Initially, I was trying to do something like this for the 0 and 1 case:

```
yield return (new[] { 0, 1 }).Take(n);
```

So that it would nicely handle cases where n was 0, 1 or greater. Unfortunately C# doesn't allow mixing of returning complete enumerables with yield statements, so that didn't work.

So here are my questions for what I want to improve:

- Is there a way I can avoid the if branches there and somehow elegantly and concisely deal with both degenerate cases?
- Is there a way I can avoid having that variable initialization statement at the beginning of the function, or even better, avoid having to keep the two variables at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider breaking it up into two methods: one, `Fibonacci()`, that represents the infinite* Fibonacci sequence, and another, `Fibonacci(int)`, that just returns `Fibonacci().Take(n)`. This removes the branching.

An implementation might look like this:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Fibonacci(int n)
{
    return Fibonacci().Take(n);
}

static IEnumerable<int> Fibonacci()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return a;
        int c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
}
```

* Well, the first 47 values that fit in an `int`.